# "far from being to be labelled"

Tags: infinitives

*Although this book is not easy to read, it is far **from being to be labelled** as an example of pseudointellectual postmodern rhetoric.*

Do you find this sentence OK? Particularly I am not sure about the phrase "it is far from being to be labelled". The sentence like "he is far from being stupid" is clear but is it permitted to use the infinitive in this case?

Comment: Remove the extraneous "to be" and it should be OK.

Comment: I think the construction you're groping for here would have to be expressed as *X is far from being **capable of being** labeled as Y*. Which to be honest is so convoluted (both semantically and syntactically) that I suggest it would be better to forget about the (hypothetical) "labeling" completely - just say the book is ***far from being*** [whatever it definitely isn't].

Comment: ...bear in mind that if you *really* meant to say that what the book is far from is being *labeled* as something, that might simply be because it hasn't been given enough critical attention to have yet been labeled as anything at all.

Comment: "Far from being labelled" is far from making sense. +1 to FumbleFingers.

Comment: You could say "It may be difficult, but it is *a far cry* from pseudointellectual postmodern rhetoric".

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost but is he removes the "to be" I'd bet he will be changing the original authors intent. My best guess at the original meaning would be "While this book is complex it is far from being [so bad] that it could be labelled as an example of ..." Essentially what MadWard reworded it to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### [Something] is to be [past participle of a verb]

This is a grammatically correct sentence.

You can see this idiom in the well-know expression:

> He is a force to be reckoned with.

In your example, the positive form might help you:

> This book is to be labelled as an example of pseudointellectual postmodern rhetoric.

Which would mean "This book **should** be labelled as [...]".

In a more general sense, to say that *Something is to be [past participle of a verb]*, for example *This person is to be blamed for his actions* means that people, in general, **should** blame him for his actions.

### In your case

Basically:

> Even though this book is not easy to read, it **shouldn't**, in any way, be labelled as an example of pseudointellectual postmodern rhetoric.

Though, in this case, I find your sentence to be very clumsy and would find a sentence with **should**, along the lines of the one I presented, more appropriate and better-sounding.

Comment: To me the original sentence (unlike all the positive ones you mention and the negative one with should) is decidedly ungrammatical.